# Roman integers to integeres - Simple

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, roman-numerals

The assignment asks to convert a roman integer into an integer. BUt without the grammar associated with roman integers (i.e IV != 4 IV = 6) I am trying to make my code more efficient...

Here is my original code:

```
def roman_v2():
    s = input("Enter a roman number using capital letters M, D, C, X, V and I: ")
    count = 0
    r_nums = ["M","D","C","X","V","I"]
    for letter in s:
        if letter in r_nums[0]:
            count += 1000
        elif letter in r_nums[1]:
            count += 500
        elif letter in r_nums[2]:
            count += 100
        elif letter in r_nums[3]:
            count += 10
        elif letter in r_nums[4]:
            count += 5
        elif letter in r_nums[5]:
            count += 1    
    return count
```

And here is my program with errors:

```
def roman_v2():
    s = input("Enter a roman number using capital letters M, D, C, X, V and I: ")
    count = 0
    r_nums = [["M",1000],["D",500],["C",100],["X",10],["V",5],["I",1]]
    for i in s:
        for j in range(0,5):
            if s[i] == r_nums[j][0]:
                count += r_nums[i][1]
    return count
```

Comment: `IV` do equals to `4`

Comment: I know, but for the sake of the assignment all we need to do is I + V == 1 + 5 == 6

Comment: Please post your errors. I feel like a `dict` is more appropriate. Also, your indentation is off.

Comment: if int(s[i]) == int(r_nums[j][0]):
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: And I uploaded it wrong in my actual program the indentation is correct :)

Comment: Use a dictionary and `sum` the retrieved values.

Comment: `i` is each char of the string, so what do you expect when using `s[i]`?

Comment: That error is because `for i in s` will iterate the character is string s. You don't need s[i] because i is already the character you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if s[i] == r_nums[j][0]:
```

should be

```
if i == r_nums[j][0]:
```

as i will be the character, not the index.

And in `count += r_nums[i][1]`, the i is wrong and should be j.

Giving you

```
def roman_v2():
    s = input("Enter a roman number using capital letters M, D, C, X, V and I: ")
    count = 0
    r_nums = [["M",1000],["D",500],["C",100],["X",10],["V",5],["I",1]]
    for i in s:
        for j in range(0,5):
            if i == r_nums[j][0]:
                count += r_nums[j][1]
    return count
```

Comment: I am still getting an error with this modifictation?     count += r_nums[i][1]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: I just saw that as I checked this!! Thank you very much!

Comment: Thanks @sam2090, saw one error and didn't check the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can tighten up your code with a dictionary and the `sum()` function:

```
def roman_v2():
    s = input("Enter a roman number using capital letters M, D, C, X, V and I: ")
    numbers = {'M':1000, 'D':500, 'C':100, 'X':10, 'V':5, 'I':1}
    return sum(numbers[num] for num in s)
```

This will look up the value for each letter, add them all up, and return the total. Error checking (for bad inputs, like `'MMpotato'`) is up to you.

Comment: @cdonts according to OP `IV` is supposed to be `6`. Look at comments under the question

Comment: @cdonts - It's supposed to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dict` in python:

```
def roman_v2():
    s = s = input("Enter a roman number using capital letters M, D, C, X, V and I: ")
    r_nums = {'M': 1000, 'D': 500, 'C': 100, 'X': 10, 'V': 5, 'I': 1}
    count = 0
    for i in s:
        count += r_nums.get(i)
    return count
```